# Splitting text file to create corpus in R

Tags: r

I have a text file with 100 articles. Each article ends with word **Document** followed by a **space** and then an **alphanumeric**. The alphanumeric is 25 characters long.

Examples of how four article ends.The alphanumeric has no set pattern.

- Document AFNR000020161206ecc700006
- Document TEKMET0020161202ecc200008
- Document AFNR000020161130ecc10001o
- Document AFNR000020161127ecbs00018

My code to read Text file in R and split text files

```
textfile <- "Text.txt"
TextData <-readLines(textfile)
head(TextData)
length(TextData)

 nchar(TextData)
 TextData = strsplit(TextData, "<Document>" "[a-zA-Z0-9]")
```

I am stuck with using **strsplit** to create a split across **Document alphanumeric**.

Once I split I can create a corpus:

```
library(tm)
doc.vec <- VectorSource(TextData)
corpusDoc <- Corpus(doc.vec)
summary(corpusDoc)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your data looks like, but assuming it is just one long string and the "Document alphanumeric code" is in line with the rest of the text, the following should work:

```
# mock data
TextData <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam egestas sapien eu leo rutrum, non commodo metus auctor. Quisque id libero quis augue bibendum auctor sed vel odio. Aliquam quam odio, maximus vitae elit at, pharetra volutpat nulla. Nam iaculis mattis lectus, sit amet euismod neque ornare consectetur. Cras nec nibh sit amet massa laoreet tempor sit amet in sem. Sed pulvinar sapien risus, molestie cursus augue rhoncus sed. Donec ullamcorper tellus vel tortor finibus pretium. Sed non tristique nisi. Document AFNR000020161206ecc700006 Vestibulum quis risus pulvinar elit blandit faucibus sed et massa. Phasellus non arcu vulputate, aliquam felis sit amet, pellentesque lorem. Praesent ut felis pellentesque, tincidunt risus imperdiet, vehicula ante. Donec odio sapien, vulputate sed semper at, pharetra sit amet dui. Fusce aliquam ullamcorper nunc in ullamcorper. Suspendisse vitae ex aliquam turpis vestibulum semper at ut quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam varius, risus sed feugiat mollis, nunc urna hendrerit mi, eu cursus erat mi quis ligula. Maecenas sit amet sagittis tellus. Donec ultricies faucibus ipsum id mattis. Ut lacinia, diam nec dignissim vestibulum, nibh augue tincidunt dolor, eu dictum felis augue in elit. Sed et scelerisque felis. Document TEKMET0020161202ecc200008 Aenean ut erat mattis, convallis orci eget, tincidunt massa. Integer dictum in erat et ornare. Donec et cursus eros. Aenean condimentum erat in lacus dictum, ac convallis tortor venenatis. Donec luctus dapibus aliquam. Maecenas et ipsum ac lacus convallis luctus. Phasellus volutpat risus sit amet volutpat vestibulum. Vestibulum eu elit sed massa imperdiet congue id interdum odio. Document AFNR000020161130ecc10001o Proin et accumsan nisi. Suspendisse tempus accumsan mollis. Integer aliquam fermentum consequat. Nunc sit amet suscipit tellus, in fringilla diam. Nulla rutrum elit nec blandit varius. Praesent vehicula nibh orci, nec facilisis sem vulputate non. Cras vel ipsum eleifend, vulputate ante congue, facilisis ligula. Integer ac mollis nibh. Ut vitae lacus eget mauris ultrices iaculis non eget diam. Praesent placerat lorem id ante maximus cursus. Ut quis lacus nec turpis tincidunt sagittis lacinia at tortor. Cras vitae posuere diam. Maecenas ut convallis lacus, in commodo neque. Sed rhoncus cursus arcu, nec pharetra odio lacinia quis. Sed nec neque libero. Etiam sit amet purus eros. Document AFNR000020161127ecbs0001"

# split on desired string
TextData <- strsplit(TextData, "Document [a-zA-Z0-9]{25}")

# if you want it as a vecotr
TextData <- unlist(TextData)
```

Seems like the problem was with the way you defined the regular expression in your `strsplit` function.